# Add a JScrollpane that split between JSplitpane and JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, split, jscrollpane

I'm just trying to insert a scrollpane, but I'm not going to get it. I have 3 areas defined by a panel. The left area to the middle is separated by a splitpane. The middle area is separated by a scrollpane. Well clear vertical from top to bottom. I hope you can help me because I am currently really frustrated and no answer to my solution.

Here is a Picture which shows what my goal is to create.

[image]

In this Method we define the split and return this to the JFrame.

```
 public JSplitPane defineSplit() {
    JPanel leftPanel = leftArea();
    JPanel centerPanel = middleArea();
    JPanel rightPanel = rightArea();
    JSplitPane splitPane1 = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, leftPanel, centerPanel);
    JSplitPane splitPane2 = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, splitPane1,rightPanel);
    splitPane1.setVisible(true);
    splitPane2.setVisible(true);
    return splitPane2;
}
```

Here is my Method which creates the content and return the Information to defineSplit().

```
public JPanel leftArea() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    panel.add(new JLabel("left area"));
    return panel;
}

public JPanel middleArea() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    panel.add(new JLabel("middle area"));
    return panel;
}

public JPanel rightArea() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    panel.add(new Label("right area"));
    return panel;
}
```

The last one is my Frame. My frame is in a extra class. Here you can just see the method.

```
public void createFrame() {
    setJMenuBar(AnimeMenuBar.getInstance().createMenu(this));
    setTitle("Anime");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 500));
    JSplitPane splitPane = content.defineSplit();
    add(splitPane);
    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**defineSplit() method:**

```
public JSplitPane defineSplit() {
    JPanel leftPanel = leftArea();
    JScrollPane centerScrollPane = middleArea();
    JPanel rightPanel = rightArea();
    JSplitPane splitPane1 = new JSplitPane();
    JSplitPane splitPane2 = new JSplitPane();

    splitPane1.setOrientation(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
    splitPane1.setRightComponent(splitPane2);
    splitPane1.setLeftComponent(leftPanel);
    splitPane2.setOrientation(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
    splitPane2.setRightComponent(rightPanel);
    splitPane2.setLeftComponent(centerPanel);

    return splitPane1;
}
```

**middleArea() method:**

```
public JScrollPane middleArea() {
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    return scrollPane;
}
```

Comment: it looks great, but I suffering by adding the Scrollpane. I tried to input it on setOrientation but it is an illigal argument.

Comment: sorry...didn't get you :(

Comment: @sharpGregor can you share the whole code you were trying...may be I can help you

Comment: If you look at my Question I post a Picture about the result what I am trying to achieve. The main Problem was not the Splitpane. The main Problem was how to split the 2 Panels middle and right with an Scrollbar(Scrollpane). But ty anyway. Eid Mubarek

Comment: sry i cant post the hole code its to much and i can get banned

Comment: Well, you may share your code via some 3rd party tools and let me know the link of that. May be you can use https://codeshare.io/new

Comment: And Eid Mubarak to you, too. Just to know, are you a Muslim? :)

Comment: Ow..I think now I have got you...but the image you posted, is that yours? If it is not, then may be you are having some misjudgement about the image. As far as I could understand, no scroll-bar is separating the two panel. Actually there are two panels in left and right and a `jScrollPane` at the middle. So, To add that facility in your code just modify the `middleArea()` method to a `jScrollPane` and keep everything as it is. I have modified my answer.

Comment: Let me know if it helps